# What is this es6 assignment operator?

Tags: javascript, operators, destructuring

If this operator declared:

`const { assign, isEmpty, run } = Ember;`

Then, instead of:

```
Ember.run(() => { ... });
Ember.assign(foo, {});
```

It can be written as:

```
run(() => { ... });
assign(foo, {});
```

Which is much nicer!

What is it and how does it work?

Note: I'll edit this question to make it clearer when I know...

Comment: It's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called **destructuring** and yes, it's very nice. Very convenient for cleaning up your code.

As explained by MDN:

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Full reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment